# Redirect after DB.query in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to redirect to a different URL after a database query in Express. The DB query executes successfully but then nothing happens.

```
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        console.log(req.body.password);
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);
        console.log(hashedPassword);
        db.query('INSERT INTO users(username, password,accessId) VALUES(?,?, 1);', [req.body.email, hashedPassword]);

        res.redirect('/login');
    }
    catch {

        res.redirect('/register');
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give entire path,

like

```
res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url + '/login');
```